# Using malloc correctly

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to refresh my C skills. Let's say I'm trying to perform a `malloc` and a `calloc`:

```
void* allocate_array(size_t member_size, size_t nmember,bool clear)
       if(clear){
            void *cal = calloc(nmember, sizeof(member_size));
            return cal;
       } else if(!clear) {
            void *mal = (void *)malloc(sizeof(member_size));
            return mal;
       }
```

I think I'm using calloc correctly here but I am unsure if I am using malloc correctly. It confuses me when I need to return void.

Comment: Why are you casting `void *` to `void *`? You don't ever need to cast from `void *`.

Comment: never cast malloc in C

Comment: @iharob: Even stranger: He does not cast consistently. `calloc()` is not casted.

Comment: Only cast if 1) you really have to. 2) you fully understand **all** implications of the cast and 3) fully accept them.

Comment: In trying to refresh memory, man pages do help a lot, especially for someone who used to use the language. They're searchable on google now. Welcome back to writing in C.

Comment: Sorry for nit-picking, wouldn't the `else` condition already imply `!clear` by virtue of being the else condition of the `if (clear)` condition? Arguably, compilers can optimize it out.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to always use `malloc`, then use `memset` if `clear` is true?

Comment: This is some bad usage of `if ... if else`. You have a boolean argument here! (I doubt that would ever have been different).

Comment: note: the function could be greatly simplified to `return calloc(nmember, member_size);`.   Unless your goal is to try and find RSA keys in memory that was previously freed without being scrubbed, or something like that.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty embarrassing code. I appreciate everyone's advice on how to clean it up and the solution to the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in both cases: `malloc` and `calloc`.

`malloc` will allocate the number of bytes you tell it to.

You call `malloc(sizeof(member_size))`:
Variable `member_size` has type `size_t` (more-or-less an `int`).
`sizeof(size_t)` is 4-bytes (on many platforms).
So, `sizeof(member_size)` is 4-bytes, and you are calling `malloc(4)`.

I don't think you want 4 bytes.
I think you want `malloc(nmember * member_size)`

---

Similarly, for calloc, you want: `calloc(nmember, member_size)`

I don't know why you're throwing in random `sizeof` calls for no good reason.

Comment: does it really make sense to return `void *` ?

Comment: Same applies to `calloc()`. It will allocate `nmember` of size 4. Kindly add in your nice answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `malloc(nmember * member_size)`?

Comment: @FredLarson - you're probably thinking of `calloc()`. For `malloc()` only allocating 1 member, it should be `malloc(member_size)`.

Comment: @alvits: Wouldn't we want the `malloc()` call to allocate the same amount of memory as the `calloc()` call? Otherwise, the `nmember` parameter is unused in the `malloc()` case. That would seem strange to me.

Comment: `size_t` **is** an integer. Not "more or less".

Comment: @Olaf:  size_t is an *unsigned* type, which already makes it slightly different from a signed int.   Also, there is no guarantee in the spec that it be an integer.  It can be a completely different data-type, using a different encoding scheme (e.g. not twos complement).   It is *almost always* an unsigned int.   But there is no guarantee of that.  Hence, "more-or-less".

Comment: @FredLarson - From the post, it would seem the OP used the flag `clear` to allocate an array or a single member. If both the `if` and `else` does the same thing, what's the point of having an `if` condition?

Comment: @alvits:  When `clear` is **ON**, it calls CALLOC, zeroing out memory.  When `clear` is **OFF**, it calls MALLOC, leaving the memory uninitialized (potentially filled with unknown values).  That is the difference.

Comment: @abelenky: `size_t` is an _unsigned_ **integer** type. The C standard does not know an "unsigned type". `int` also is an integer type. Signeness is not a property of an integer by default. See 6.2.5p4 and p6. And the standard very well mandates it is an (unsigned) integer, see 7.19p2! And the encoding of an _unsigned integer_ is exactly defined.

Comment: @abelenky - I totally agree with the behavior of `malloc()` and `calloc()`. But we're both just guessing what the OP's intent for the flag `clear`. Although your assumption may be closer to the OP's intent, hence the name `clear`.

Comment: @alvits: No: if you understand English, the intention is clear (pun): Does the caller want the memory cleared out, then they pass True-or-False. True for "cleared", False for "uninitialized".

Comment: @abelenky Concerning "no guarantee in the spec that it (`size_t`) be an integer".  I _think_ it might have been that way in earlier C.  In C11 "`size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator;"  C11 §7.19 2.

Comment: I don't want to make another question, but if I wanted to deallocate an array:
`deallocate_array(void** ptr)`
traverse through the array freeing, and then call another free?

Comment: Why don't you want to make another question?   Do questions contribute to global warming?  Is someone charging you a dollar-per-question?  NO?  Then make another question!

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean the following

```
void * allocate_array( size_t member_size, size_t nmember, bool clear )
{
    return clear ? calloc( nmember, member_size ) : malloc( nmember * member_size );
}
```

As for your function definition then neither the call of `calloc` nor the call of `malloc` is correct.

Take into account that this if statement

```
   if(clear){
       // ... 
   } else if(!clear) {
       // ... 
   }
```

is better to write like

```
   if(clear){
       // ... 
   } else {
       // ... 
   }
```

The last record is more clear,